# What are the Rules-As-Written limits on a Paladin's ability to work with demons?

Tags: paladin

The situation came up in my group where a demon offered us a temporary alliance with itself in order to kill a dragon.

We have a Paladin in our group.  I would have thought a Paladin would flat out refuse to work with a demon, but my group ruled it was for the greater good.

**What consequences does this have for the Paladin (by the rules)?**

Comment: Which game and version? Please edit that into the question.

Comment: Even with game and version, we don't do alignment questions here because in the end they are pure opinion. "Would a good X do Y?" Maybe yes maybe no, and it's only up to you and your GM.  http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5357/what-kinds-of-alignment-questions-are-on-topic

Comment: @mxyzplk should it be D&D 3.x, it's not about "what is good" or "what is bad", which are opinionable. It's "what is clearly written in the most clear fall-from-grace condition of your class" (it is not even alignment).

Comment: I've removed the portion of a suggested edit that specified 3.x, since it appears to have been approved based on good faith in its claim it was based on a comment, but on further investigation it wasn't a comment from the asker.

Comment: I misread Zachiel's comment. @SevenSidedDie's reversion is correct.

Comment: At this point, the edits have made a hash of the question.  I have added a final bolded summation and removed the question mark after a statement.  However, it seems unanswerable unless a game and edition is included.

Comment: Yeah. I've found it's sometimes simpler to leave a question's minor issues unfixed until the major issues are fixed.

Comment: In future cases, there is always that handy rollback link on revision 1.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry I not sure how to clarify.  We are playing D&D v2.  There have been times in the game where my character has not been able to do certain things such as summoning skeletons and such because it would be considered an evil act and therefore upset the paladin, but then we came across an opportunity to ally with a demon and the paladin had no problem with that, I argued differently otherwise why cannot I summon skeletons to assist us, it was argued that allying with the demon would be for the greater good, and I argued that could apply to anything if we are going down that route.

Comment: @DemonDan V2? Do you mean [*Advance Dungeons and Dragons (AD&D) 2nd edition?*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Editions_of_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Advanced_Dungeons_.26_Dragons_2nd_edition)